# Play framework module vs sub-project

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

I couldn't understand the difference between module and sub projects. What's the difference and which one should be used for moduler application.

Answer (score 3):

With both approaches you can compile, run and test code individually. 
With subprojects you can share settings and it is connected to project that depends on it with the *source code*:

> When you run your Play application in dev mode, the dependent projects are automatically recompiled, and if something cannot compile you will see the result in your browser.
>   (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/SBTSubProjects)

A play module just a JAR dependency which can be structured like a play application.
So you depend on a *binary*.

Both ways are for building modular applications, maybe a subproject is easier to handle, but a module makes more sense if you want wo share code between multiple play apps.

Comment: does it mean that the best way to develop some module from scratch is to make it as subproject first? Thus is could be tested from main project and no need to care about compiling module into the jar everytime in orde to use it from main app (while developing)?

Comment: That is an interesting idea and should be evaluated. I use "~publish-local" to automatically build and deploy a module for an example or test App.